# How to access/return values from mongo document with mongoose query and async-await/Promise?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, promise, async-await

I have used mongoDB but I am new to Node.js and mongoose and I am trying to get a grasp on using mongoose with async-await/Promises. I am creating an React/Node with web sockets (socket.io) app where users can create an account and log in if they already have an account. I have been able to successfully create and execute a mongo/mogoose query but I am having problems with using the document once I have it. This is what my code looks like:

```
const profileRoute = (action, io) => {
    switch (action.cmd) {
        case 'LOGIN':
            getProfile(action.email)
                .then(profile => {
                    console.log('profile: ', profile)     // prints the mongo document properly.
                    console.log('email: ', profile.email) // email: undefined
                    io.emit('action', {
                        type: PROFILE_LOGIN,
                        email: profile.email,
                        name: profile.name,
                    });
                .catch(err => {console.log(err)});
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
};
```

And this is what "getProfile()" looks like:

```
export const getProfile = async (email) => {
    const tempPromise = collection.findOne({ email }).exec();
    try {
        return await tempPromise;
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return {};
    } 
};
```

I have also tried to symplify "getProfile()" since async-await wouldn't help much here (just wanted to try something small to get started) to this:

```
export const getProfile = (email) => {
    return collection.findOne({ email }).exec();
};
```

But either way I try when I print "profile.email" it is undefined and my result from

```
io.emit('action', {
    type: PROFILE_LOGIN,
    email: profile.email,
    name: profile.name,
});
```

is:

```
{
    type: PROFILE_LOGIN,
}
```

but if I do this:

```
io.emit('action', {
    type: PROFILE_LOGIN,
    profile: profile,
});
```

the result is:

```
{
    type: PROFILE_LOGIN,
    profile: {correct mongo document},
}
```

But I only need/want a few values from the mongo document.

Also, if there is a better way to rewrite "profileRoute()" (I know this question isn't really about that) using async-await I am open to suggestions.

EDIT: There was a typo when I originally wrote this question. Changed:

```
{
    type: PROFILE_LOGIN,
    profile: [correct mongo document],
}
```

This more accurately reflects the return from ".findOne()":

```
{
    type: PROFILE_LOGIN,
    profile: {correct mongo document},
}
```

Comment: I think that the result you get is an array of objects matching the query. try to print profile[0].email

Comment: ".findOne()" only returns a single document so it is typeof == 'object' and not an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const profileRoute = async (action, io) => {
  switch (action.cmd) {
    case 'LOGIN':
      try {
        const profile = await getProfile(action.email);
        if (!profile) {
          throw new Error(`Profile with email ${action.email} not found`);
        }
        io.emit('action', {
          type: PROFILE_LOGIN,
          email: profile.email,
          name: profile.name
        });
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
      }
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
};
```

And your `getProfile()` code would simply be:

```
export const getProfile = email => {
  return collection.findOne({ email }).exec();
};
```

Answer (score -1):

```
export const getProfile = async (email) => {
    const tempPromise = collection.findOne({ email }).exec();
    try {
        return await tempPromise;
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return {};
    }  };
```

You should add await in front of `collection.findOne`
And if you wanna only get json object, you can add lean() in the end of mongoose query like this.

```
export const getProfile = async (email) => {
    const tempPromise = await collection.findOne({ email }).lean().exec();
    try {
        return await tempPromise;
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return {};
    } 
};
```

Comment: This worked! With how this is setup is the await necessary in front of `collection.findOne()`? I tried it both ways (with adding .lean() both times) and it seems to be working both ways.

Comment: This makes no sense. An `await`ed expression never resolves to a `tempPromise` that could subsequently be `await`ed again.

Comment: In the second example tempPromise is not a promise, it is a JSON object, so it can't be awaited again.

Comment: tempPromise is not Promise but collection exec() has promise function so it just return promise return value and lean() is supporting json object to reduce the mongoose query size.